# Need help rewriting an Nginx rule for subdomain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I did a little rewrite rule a little while ago to redirect ppl who directly access my site's image to image pages instead,

for example a person accessing www.mysite.com/i/asdf.jpg to www.mysite.com/pic/asdf

this is the rewrite rule i used :

```
location /i/image_(\d+).(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
  root /home/mysite/public_html;
  valid_referers www.example.com mysite.com;
  if ($invalid_referer) {
   rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/pic/$1 permanent;
  }
 }
```

I made a subdomain of the directory 'i' which contains all the images. so its like thsi now http://i.mysite.com/

Is it possible to make a rewrite like the one above so if the file is directly accessed by a different referer it will hit the same rewrite rule ?

thx :)

UPDATE : 
now using this :

```
   server {
 access_log off;

  error_log  logs/vhost-error_log warn;
  listen    80;
  server_name i.imgzzz.com;
    root /home/imgzzz/public_html;
  #location ~ ^/pic/ { alias /home/imgzzz/public_html/i; }
        location ~ ^/pic/(.*)$ { alias /home/imgzzz/public_html/i/$1; }
valid_referers i.imgzzz.com www.imgzzz.com imgzzz.com;
location ~ /image_(\d+).(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        rewrite /image_(\d+).(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ /pic/image_$1 last;
    }
}
}
```

Htaccess rewrites :

```
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks
#RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^imgzzz.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.imgzzz.com/$1 [r=301,nc] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?imgzzz.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule i/image_(\d+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif) pic/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^pic/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ view.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^pic/full/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ view-f.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^pic/([0-9]+)/feature/$ view.php?name=$1&pop=1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
valid_referers i.imgzzz.com www.imgzzz.com imgzzz.com;
location ~ /image_(\d+).(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        rewrite /image_(\d+).(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ /view.php?name=image_$1.$2 last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, k let me explain a little, an image direct link can be accessed two ways. www.mysite.com/i/aabc.jpg and i.mysite.com/aabc.jpg . Now if a user accesss directly the first way is rewrited to the image page. but if runs via subdomain then isn't thts what i m trying to do to get the user to redirect to page if accessed the image via subdomain . sorry my bad english i hoep i made u understand what i mean.

Comment: So the redirect is needed for the www.mysite.com, but _not_ for the i.mysite.com subdomain, is that right?

Comment: k let me clarify more, check thsi out . http://www.imgzzz.com/i/image_1295618489.jpg if you run this jpg link it will open within the page instead of direct image link. but if u run this jpg link from the subdomain(same folder) http://i.imgzzz.com/image_1295618489.jpg it opens directly that's what im trying to avoid, i want it to do the same thing as teh first one did.

Comment: Does i.imgzzz.com declared as a separate "server" in nginx config? If so, repeat the rewrite with the referer condition there and add an unconditional /pic/ location

Comment: Yes its declared as a seperate server, not sure about the unconditional location, plz check tweet

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example with "i" subdomain server

Comment: Helo, k i have tried it, but now it isn't getting the image name and stops by this place at url and gives a 404 : i.mysite.com/pic/ .. there shud be image nameat the end like i.mysite.com/pic/1234567 or something. better take a look : http://i.imgzzz.com/image_1295445934.jpg thx

Comment: Because the rewrite does not see $1 as i told you. now the example has the updated rewrite

Comment: Hey, it seems we are almost there check what i am getting nwo : http://i.imgzzz.com/pic/image_1295445934.jpg cheers. redirection error of some sort.

Comment: Does i.mysite.com server have "location /pic/ {}" *as in the example*?

Comment: yes in the server {} it does. but not physically in this directory. i copy pasted the entire as you put above just renamed mysite to domain name. rest is same.

Comment: Let's try with "location ~ ^/pic/ {}"

Comment: no luck now im getting a 404 on it. i have added the current code top in edit. please check

Comment: Do the images reside in /home/imgzzz/public_html/pic? If not, set the "location ~ ^/pic/ { alias /the/real/path/to/pic; }"

Comment: it reside in public_html/i/ . so it would  location ~ ^/pic/ { alias /imgzzz/public_html/i; } ?

Comment: still a 404, i tried both location ~ ^/pic/ { alias /imgzzz/public_html/i; } and location ~ ^/pic/ { alias /home/imgzzz/public_html/i; }

Comment: What does the error log say? nginx usually writes where it tries to look for the requested file

Comment: its my first time with nginx where can i check it log ?  if its in logs/vhost-error.log ... then is 445MBs of size.. lol i don't think i will be able to download that soon

Comment: k i found this in the error.log file in same directory , 
2011/01/23 18:55:41 [error] 621#0: *3488788 open() "/home/mysite/public_html/i/image_1295819570.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 119.152.7.178, server: i.imgzzz.com, request: "GET /image_1295819570.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "i.imgzzz.com"

Comment: make sure the "alias" is "/home/imgzzz/public_html/i". and check if the file really exist

Comment: due to some reason its adding a slash in the very end after .jpg .. check http://i.imgzzz.com/pic/image_1295445934.jpg  yes both file exists and alias fixed as well.

Comment: Ok, now let's try "location ~ ^/pic/(.*)$ { alias /home/imgzzz/public_html/i/$1; }"

Comment: hmm k now try the same link. its loading image directly

Comment: Shouldn't it? I'm probably lost already, but up until now I thought you want to redirect everybody requesting imgzzz.com/image_X.jpg without a valid referrer to i.imgzzz.com/pic/image_X.jpg

Comment: yes exactly. but with in the paeg template like in this case as i mentioned top , run this direct link to an image. imgzzz.com/i/image_1295618489.jpg  . so same case while accessing image via subdomain. the image should load within the page template with stats, ads etc.

Comment: Ok, I'm updating the answer. If you wish to leave a separate i.imgzzz.com "server", repeat the lines there

Comment: hmm k . but in this case its redirecting to the original source page instead of keeping the same url as...jpg and showing it in the page template. like in thsi case imgzzz.com/i/image_1295618489.jpg  . it keeps the same url but load in the page layout, so i was wanting to keep teh same subdomain url but load in the page layout

Comment: There was no need to the "permanent" then. "permanent" means an explicit redirect. Updated the answer

Comment: Show the full config now, please

Comment: Remove "location ~ /pic/", don't need it anymore. I suppose the pages are in /home/imgzzz/public_html/pic/. If it doesn't eliminate the error, what's in the error log?

Comment: k i have removed that area, there doesn't seems to be anything regading thsi in error.log and i cannot download and view vhost-error.lol coz its of 450Mbs.what do u suggest?

Comment: Run a "tail vhost-error_log" command on the server. And check that the page /home/imgzzz/public_html/pic/image_1295618489 really exist

Comment: k idid that and that's what i foudn on running the file from this page. one thing i noticed it was loking for the file without the extension and in the directory /pic/ .. thou the directory for images is /i/ whihc its rewerited as /pic/
2011/01/29 13:58:26 [error] 16282#0: *9678823 open() "/home/imgzzz/public_html/pic/image_1295618489" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 119.154.91.236, server: i.imgzzz.com, request: "GET /image_1295618489.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "i.imgzzz.com", referrer: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739589/need-help-rewriting-an-nginx-rule-for-subdomain"

Comment: The page is a html file, right? What's the name? image_1295618489.html?

Comment: hmm k . let me explain the structure, image_xxxxx.(extension) are imaeg files.. jpg. png, gifs .
called via view.php(the page template rewrited as /pic/) all present in the public_html, image files are present in public_html/i 
 The main rewrite is /pic/xxx(image name which is numbers) so the view.php GET that name/number and displays that image from the i/ directory. hoep i make my self clear.

Comment: That's why I asked for the full config. What's the url of the page?

Comment: oh sorry about that i only copied the config of subdomain server in vhost..
k so its www.imgzzz.com site, www.imgzzz.com/view.php as that main file. www.imgzzz.com/view.php?name=1295618489 as teh rewriting method. What else would u require ? thx

Comment: Check the updated answer. I guess the /pic/ stuff isn't necessary at all

Comment: hmm k i am a bit confused at a couple of places, can u add the full server code in the edit. take rest from question /edit. so i can do it without any error plz

Comment: and im guessing then we will have to call the pages like this : i.imgzzz.com/view.php?name=xxx ??

Comment: I meant for the rewrite there is no need for the /pic/ in it. I don't know how the view.php kicks in. Do you have a "location /" to proxy_pass to apache? As long as /view.php?name=xxx works, the rewrite should request it now

Comment: hmm it isn't capturing it, view.php only gets the file name,,, and does the rest of the stuff, nginx is serving only static content liek css, js, images etc. reest is done via apache

Comment: You really cannot see why, can you? Updated the answer

Comment: im not sure wht did i missed in explaning u . anyways by that code if we put , and run the url : http://i.imgzzz.com/view.php?name=1296494233 it gives me view.php to download it.

Comment: Show me the full config! Otherwise how would I know how the apache is involved?

Comment: k check update i included the htaccess rules for view.php as well.

Comment: add "location /view.php { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:... }". proxy_pass & other proxy_* params you use to forward requests to apache

Comment: didn't worked, and i gave up on it :( . thx for all the help man

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. What a mess we've left here. Anyway, if you feel like we could give it a second chance, you know my e-mail (from my profile). I'll really need full nginx config to see how some requests are proxied to apache and the rest.